# How can I simplify $\frac{\sin(1) + \sin(2) + \cdots + \sin(100)}{\cos(1) + \cos(2) + \cdots +\cos(100)}$

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-functions

So I was asked to simplify the expression 
$$\frac{\sin(1) + \sin(2) + \cdots + \sin(100)}{\cos(1) + \cos(2) + \cdots + \cos(100)}.$$ I'm struggling to find a way of doing it.

I'd like just hints rather than a whole solution if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Radians or degrees?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Doesn't matter. All that will be used is that the arguments form an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$\sin(kt) = \mathbb{Im}(e^{ikt})$
and
$\cos(kt) = \mathbb{Re}(e^{ikt})$.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use the identities

$\sin A + \sin B = 2 \sin \frac{A+B}{2} \cos \frac{A-B}{2}$

and

$\cos A + \cos B = 2 \cos  \frac{A+B}{2} \cos \frac{A-B}{2}$

Start by rearranging the fraction as:

$$\frac{(\sin 100+\sin1)+(\sin 99+\sin2)+...+(\sin 51+\sin50)}{(\cos  100+\cos  1)+(\cos 99+\cos  2)+...+(\cos  51+\cos 50)}$$